# A script that logs in to multiple websites at once. CURL and PHP tried.

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I run a computer lab for grade schoolers (3-14 y.o.) and would like to create a desktop/dashboard page consisting of a number of iframes, each pointing at a different external website 
(for which we have created individual accounts for each child); and when a kid logs in (to the dashboard) a script will log her in to those websites, so she does not have to.

I have 1 server and 20 workstations, I'll refer to them as 'myserver' and 'mybrowser'(s) respectively. All these behind the same router (dynamic IP).

A kid gets on a 'mybrowser' workstation, fires up Firefox and runs desktop.php (hosted in 'myserver') and gets a login screen (for 'myserver')

'mybrowser' ---http---> 'myserver'

Once logged in, 'myserver' will retrieve a set of username and password stored in its database and run a CURL script to send those to an 'external web server'.

'mybrowser' ---http---> 'myserver' ---curl---> 'external web server'

SUCCESSFUL, well, I thought.
Turns out CURL, being run off 'myserver', logs in 'myserver' instead of 'mybrowser'. 
The session inside the iframe, after refresh, is still NOT logged in. Now I know.

Then I thought of capturing the cookies from 'myserver' and set it into 'mybrowser' so that 'mybrowser' can now browse (within the iframe)
 as a logged in user. After all, we (all the 'mybrowsers') are behind the same router as 'myserver', thus same IP address.

So in other words, I only need 'myserver' to log a user in to several external websites all at once ,and once done pass the control over back to individual users' browsers.

I hope the answer will not resort to using CURL to display and control the external websites for the whole session, aside from being a drag that will lead to some other sticky issues.

I am getting the nuance that this is not permitted due to security issues, but what if all the 'mybrowsers' and 'myserver' are behind the same router? Assuming there's a way to copy the login cookies from 'myserver' to 'mybrowsers', would 'external web server' know that a request came from different machines?

Can this be done?
Thanks.

Comment: What authentication mechanisms do your various services use? Basic authentication or specific login pages?  It strikes me that the correct solution will require Javascript from each browser.

Comment: If you are trying to log the `mybrowser` workstations themselves in, using a request that was initiated from `myserver`, then the short answer is "No". The long answer is "Yes, but it would require so much messing around that it's just not worth the bother". This is because the scope of both HTTP auth and cookies is restricted to a host, and the long of the short of it is that you would have to build a full proxy running on `myserver`, or mess around with the hosts file on all the workstations - you need the workstations that the `myserver`s identity is all those external sites, briefly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing relates to the security principles of cookies. You cannot set cookies for other domains, which means that `myserver` cannot set a cookie for facebook.com, for example.

You could set your server to run an HTTP proxy and make it so that all queries run through your server and do some kind of URL translation (e.g. facebook.com => facebook.myserver) which then in return allows you to set cookies for the clients (since you're running on facebook.myserver) and then translates cookies you receive from the clients and feed them to the third party websites.

An example of a non-transparent proxy that you could begin with: http://www.phpmyproxy.com/

Transparent proxies (in which URLs remain "correct" / untranslated) might be worth considering too. [Squid](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.squid-cache.org/&ei=QSljT4rfDIHm8QP355HlBw&usg=AFQjCNH4y54xeStwUpGJn4JTxudkaMMLoA) is a pretty popular one. Can't say how easy this would be, though.

After all that you'll still need to build a local script for `myserver` that takes care of the login process, but at least a proxy should make it all possible.

If you have any say in the login process itself, it might be easier to set up all the services to use OpenID or similar login services, StackOverflow and its sister sites being a prime example on how easy login on multiple sites can be achieved.